moment.js not defined in odoo module
while i try to use moment in odoo module it through some error like this :
The following modules are needed by other modules but have not been defined, they may not be present in the correct asset bundle:
moment
The following modules could not be loaded because they have unmet dependencies, this is a secondary error which is likely caused by one of the above problems:
@my_dashboard/components/sales_dashboard
import { registry } from "@web/core/registry"
import { KpiCard } from "./kpi_card/kpi_card"
import { ChartRenderer } from "./chart_renderer/chart_renderer"
import { loadJS } from "@web/core/assets"
import moment from 'moment';
import { useService } from "@web/core/utils/hooks"
const { Component, onWillStart, useRef, onMounted, useState } = owl

export class OwlSalesDashboard extends Component {
    setup(){
        this.state=useState({
            quotations:{
                value:10,
                percentage:6,
            },
            period:90,
        })
        this.orm=useService("orm")
        onWillStart(async() => {
            await this.getQuotations()
        })
    }
    onChangePeriod() {
        console.log(this.state.period)
        console.log(moment().format())
    }
    async getQuotations(){
        const data = await this.orm.searchCount("sale.order",[['state','in',['send','draft']]])
        this.state.quotations.value = data
    }
}

OwlSalesDashboard.template = "owl.OwlSalesDashboard"
OwlSalesDashboard.components = { KpiCard, ChartRenderer }

registry.category("actions").add("owl.sales_dashboard", OwlSalesDashboard)

Error Screenshot
sales_dashboard.js
moment installed successfully
please give correct answer

moment recommend using luxon which is already available in Odoo

Luxon can be thought of as the evolution of Moment

Odoo migrated (Odoo 16):
moment().format()  

To (Odoo 17):
DateTime.now().toFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ")


it's okay brother , i want to use moment  . it's possible or not . if i'ts possible , tell me how to i done this one

You can import it like in Odoo 14, you just need to import it to the same asset bundle in the manifest file

Then you can use moment without importing it

it's not working odoo 17v  can you explain in detail  and also refer any documentation or screenshot for this .....

Try to add it to the same assets bundle like they did for luxon
